# Is there a way on how to get an access token for User Data Permission in PHP?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, access-token

I am using PHP to work on Facebook, and I want to get an access_token to get User Data Permission for items like

- email
- user_actions.music
- user_activities
- user_events
- user_location
- etc.

I know this can be done by using Graph API Explorer in Facebook developers. Can you show me how to do this in PHP? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After `include`'ing the Facebook SDK for PHP, simply call [`$facebook->getLoginUrl`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLoginUrl/) with appropriate parameters.

Comment: I only have an user account, so I don't have app_secret. it gives me an error **undefined secret**

Comment: You need an app ID and an app secret to use the Facebook SDK.

Comment: Something like this [link](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=1)

Comment: Yes, that is an App with its own AppId and Secret numbers.